# Two way binding between components in Knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I'm looking to create reusable component, I'm just not able to create the two way binding I need without a external library such as the postbox sub/pub I've seen.

Here is an example [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wpMeGN) of what I am trying to do

It's a very basic example but it shows what I need.

The `mainViewModel` has a property `name` which I need to get from the `name-input` component.

I'm used to angular 2+ and using two way bindings, does KO have something similar?

Thanks

Steve

Edit:
Javascript:

```
ko.components.register("name-input", {
  viewModel: function(params) {
    var self = this;
    self.userInput = ko.observable();
    return self;
  },
  template: "<div><input data-bind='textInput: userInput' placeholder='Enter your name'><br/>Hello,<span data-bind='text:userInput'></span></div>"
});


function mainViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.name = ko.observable();
}

ko.applyBindings(new mainViewModel(), $("#main")[0]);
```

Html:

```
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="inner-container">
      MyName:
      <div data-bind="text:name"></div>
    </div>
    <name-input></name-input>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `params` attribute to pass an observable reference for the component instance to read from and write to:

```
<name-input params="value: name"></name-input>
```

In your component's viewmodel function, you reference this value instead of creating a new observable:

```
function(params) {
  var self = this;
  self.userInput = params.value;
  return self;
}
```

[Running example in a fork of your Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GyoMGM)